# Change font size in HTML5 slides prepared with markdown -> pandoc

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm creating some HTML slides using the following workflow:

- Code is written in R Studio editor 0.97.248
- `.md` document created with `knitr` 0.8
- HTML5 slides created from `.md` file using pandoc 1.10.1

This is the workflow described by Yihui Xie [here](http://yihui.name/en/2012/05/how-to-make-html5-slides-with-knitr/); it's the most straightforward way I'm aware of to make slides for presentations using Markdown.

My problem is even a relatively short line of code (50 characters) runs off the right-hand side of the slide, because the default code font is large and widely-spaced.

For instance, the following slide

`````
# Title of the slide
And some text.

````{r plotChunk, message=FALSE, fig.height=5, fig.width=5}
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=cty, colour=class)) + geom_point()
````
`````

produces the following slide:

[image]

I could use code options `tidy=FALSE` to manually split lines of code, but I will never be able to fit much code on a line. Is there any way to make the default body font & code font smaller in the HTML document?

Comment: you can use your own template: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates and define smaller font for `pre` in CSS, e.g. `pre {font-size: 10px;}`; default template is here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.dzslides

Comment: Alternately, you could use [slidify](http://www.slidify.org) which handles the conversion of R Markdown to HTML slides entirely within R and provides support for more than 10 frameworks (including dzslides). Disclosure: I am the author of Slidify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both @Yihui and @Ramnath offer effective solutions to my problem. Since each opted to respond in comments, I'll just note that **I found `slidify` to be a quicker solution to my underlying problem, which was that I needed to modify default pandoc formatting to make pretty slides**. Compare the pandoc-created slide above with the same slide created with `slidify` below:

[image]

`slidify` picks a more appropriate code size by default.

One reason for my trouble with pandoc may be system-specific (am running Mac OSX 10.7.5, R 2.15.1, R Studio 0.97.248, pandoc 1.10.1). Pandoc's file conversion does not seem to be quite right on my system: on the figure in the question, see how the name of the chunk is printed over the plot, rather than below the plot. When I convert Yihui's slides from his `.Rmd` [source](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/009-slides.Rmd) I get different (worse) output than he did. Note the 'html' text below, which apparently is carry-over from a previous slide in which one line of text ran off the right-hand side of the screen.

[image]

Finally, the `fig.height` and `fig.width` options work as expected in `slidify`, whereas pandoc seems to re-size figures to fill the slide. Note the crappy resolution of the plot in the question - it was a small plot, and pandoc has blown it up.

I suspect pandoc will be useful for creating documents in multiple formats from RMarkdown, but for making quick slides on my system, `slidify` seems like a better solution out of the box.

Comment: You are right. Pandoc is a swiss army knife that helps convert between  multiple formats. Slidify serves a single objective in converting Rmd to HTML.